# How to use Model Validation in a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a controller like this:

```
public FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

With the Index view:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Bar/Add", new Models.Bar()); }
```

The Bar controller is like this:

```
public BarController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        return View(bar);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Bar bar)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.AddBar(bar);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Foo");
        }

        // This will return only the partial view (No Layout, no outer view)
        return View("Add", bar);

        // This will not show validation errors
        // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Foo");
    }
}
```

And the Add View looks like this:

```
@model Models.Bar

@using(Html.BeginForm("Add", "Bar", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="Add Bar" />

    @Html.ValidationSummary()
}
```

My problem is that if I return `View("Add", bar)` I get the partial view, and nothing else (not what I want). But if I instead return `RedirectToAction("Index", "Foo")` whether it passes validation or not, I of course lose any validation errors for the valiation summary.

Is there a way to use validation in a partial view like this?

Comment: why are you using [HttpGet] in you return view

Comment: well you typically do not read anythink grom get all you do here is you just pass a pure action the next post is when you read the values from post not sure if you need get

Comment: you don't *need* the Get attribute there, it's implicitly a Get method anyway. It's just a stylistic preference. But what do you mean you do not read anything from Get? Of course you do! Post means you're modifying content... not sure what you're trying to say...

Comment: it not a get method all you do there is return a object the get is typically used to read somethink like from query string or form action depending on what your form action uses post or get

Comment: are you saying that if I remove [HttpGet] it's no longer a GET method? I can assure you, it most certainly will be a GET method still. Like I said, it's purely to disambiguate from the POST method right below it. But using your own terminology, you are indeed reading *something*... how about you are reading the HTML emitted from the server? Again, I fail to see your point... HttpGet is used to restrict the method from being called using a different verb, something i like to explicitly do when I'm using the post-redirect pattern. To my knowledge, this is pretty standard practice in MVC

Comment: what kind HTML are you reading from server what are you reading in there anyway all you do is pass  http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html read this do you even know why you use get

Comment: ITS NOT A FORM!!! WHAT IS YOUR POINT???` go to google.com, watch the headers, i can assure you, your browser is using a GET request.

Comment: then why do you use post and get if it not a form

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332275/why-would-i-use-httppost-attribute-in-mvc

Comment: yep clear enough in the answer with 16 points answer the id is passed so he uses get although it not necessary he reads it from query string

Comment: look, its an incomplete example, with enough detail to illustrate my actual problem which has nothing to do with html verbs. but just for you, i'll remove it, so i can move on from this nonsense

Comment: I do not really care what you use but typically there is a reason to use something and where you would expect to put get

Comment: @COLDTOLD I think you are mixed up on the `get` vs. `post`. @ErOx is correct, the browser `gets` the page from the server then `posts` the form data to the server.

Comment: @Garrett Fogerlie not in this specific case the page or view is already created the browser does not get anything if he would pass to the page something to the browser that one think but in this case it not happening please do not mix the http term with form terms

Comment: The page is not already created in the browser, the server populates the render action then serves the entire page. I don't think `Html.RenderPartial` is a separate request.

Comment: why do you return a view than and pass object to model if he would use sometink like add(int id) as it was shown in above question than it fine although it not need because in this case he uses the get to read the id from the query string but in above example nothink is is in the query string it not needed at all it like let me read a query string that does not exist

Comment: I believe we're on the same page, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Garrett Fogerlie Html.RenderPartial I think it is a separate request since talks to another controller but not 100 percent sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could:

1. `return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")` if validation fails.
2. Save ModelState on TempData and restore it on the Home.Index action.
3. Make an AJAX request.

Comment: Right, persisting the data between the two different controllers seems like the necessary step i was missing, thanks.

Comment: @MaxToro, is my answer below wrong? And if so would you mind telling me why, thanks!

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie The issue is with model state not with view model.

Answer (score 1):

you should use @Ajax.Begin instead of using @Html.BeginForm  which will submit you request by using ajax.

@model Models.Bar

```
<div id="targetId">
</div>

        @using(Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Bar",new AjaxOptions{  HttpMethod ="POST",UpdateTargetId="targetId"}))
        {


            Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)

            <input type="submit" value="Add Bar" />

            @Html.ValidationSummary()
        }
```

it make ajax call for "Add" and in your Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Bar bar)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _repository.AddBar(bar);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Foo");
    }

    return RenderPartialViewToString("Add",bar);
}



protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

then add "RenderPartialViewToString" method which will return you "**HtmlRenderString**" here you need to pass View And model as parameter to this method.
also you must be Specified "**UpdateTargetId**" in AjxOption where your result will append.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Bar/Add", new Models.Bar()); }` with `@{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Bar/Add"); }`, the way you had it, it was trying to post a new `Bar` to the `[Post] Add` instead or getting the view.

Also, I normally use `PartialViewResult` and `return PartialView` for partial views in the controller. Not sure if it makes a difference though.

**Update**

I just pulled up a project where I have a partial form, and I access it using `@Html.Action()` and everything seems to work and validate fine. Give `@Html.RenderAction` a try. Here is a good post describing the differences. http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/