# I cant make working an httpost call on MVC ( only Get)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am trying to to a WebServiceApi(for phone app) that insert a row into a database but I cant make it works, It doesn't enter in the function.

I am using REST Easy extension of Firefox to call the post service.

I call `http://localhost:1717/api/Personas` with 3 parameters idSubvario,idPersona,idinstalacion

But the response of the server is that It cant find a resource HTTP that match with the URI, If i change to `http://localhost:1717/api/Personas?idSubvario=2&idPersona=2&idInstalacion=5190` It works, 0_o

This is the function of the Controller

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult PostPersonaSubvariosXIDSubvariosYIDPersona(int idSubvario,int idPersona, short idInstalacion)
{
    BsPersonas bPersonas = new BsPersonas();
    bPersonas.InsertarPersonaSubvario(idSubvario, idPersona, idInstalacion);

    EmptyResult er = new EmptyResult();
    return er;
}
```

Why it works like a GET petition if I say that is HttpPost?

Comment: http://localhost:1717/api/Personas :- It means you are calling a function named Personas in your apicontroller .But what i can see here is that your function name is something different .Change that and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is calling Personas function in apiController.But in your code the function is having some different name .Thats why you are getting the error.Change your function name to Personas.It will work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I changed it to the function but still not working, 
btw If I change the url to  http://localhost:1717/api/Personas?idSubvario=2&idPersona=2&idInstalacion=5190   it works :S

Comment: Thats okay.Glad i was able to provide you a help.Please mark if are happy with the answer

Comment: But why it works like a GET petition if I say that is HttpPost?

Comment: Please check this link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332275/httppost-vs-httpget-attributes-in-mvc-why-use-httppost