# Returning data to the Controller from an view with an EditorForModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to return all the object data that the EditorForModel receives from the user.  The Event object has about 5 fields. I'd like to return the entire object to the Save method in the Controller where I can do a DB update.  I can't use a foreach loop since the iEnumerator isn't available.  How do I access the data within the Actionlink?   Thanks!

```
@model EventsMVC.Models.Event

@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Edit")
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index")
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use Model or ViewData or ViewBag

Comment: You do not use an action link. You use a form in your view and you submit you data to a POST method - `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Save(Event model)`

Comment: Like this?  The object coming to the Save method is still null.  The contoller is called Database.


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Database"))

Comment: @user1327418, That will work just fine (assuming its `@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Database")) { @Html.EditorForModel() <input type="submit" /> }`. And if its not working for you, show all the relevant code including your model.

Comment: That worked!  The input type submit button did it.  The action link did not return the object data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code will be helpful for your problem:

**Your changed View Code:**

```
@model EventsMVC.Models.Event

@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
      //save - ActionName and Account(for ex)-ControllerName
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Account")) 

      { 

        @Html.EditorForModel() 
       <input type="submit" value="SubmitData" /> 

     }
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And in your Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Event eventmodel)
    {
         //your update logic here

    }
```

Hope Above information was helpful ,kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: shouldn't you add `[HttpPost]` attribute in your controller method?

Comment: @kimbaudi Thank you so much for your additional note. As you said,  even though [Httpget] and  [Httppost] is optional attribute, it is alaways good to have in all the action methods. 

Useful link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332275/httppost-vs-httpget-attributes-in-mvc-why-use-httppost

Once again thank you and I will update the answer..:)

Comment: If you don't add `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]`, then it defaults to `[HttpGet]` so I always recommend adding `[HttpPost]`. `[HttpGet]` is optional, but I like to be explicit and add it anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your question.

Usually in the controller method you include your model object as a parameter and the MVC framework will automatically fill the model object with data from your page.

something like

```
    public ActionResult Index(EventsMVC.Models.Event model)
    {
       //... do stuff with model
    }
```

these can then be referenced by the name properties in your model class directly.

Enumeration should not be required.

Comment: But how do I send that model back to the Controller method.  When I add that parameter, it is null upon return.  I need to get the stuff from the EditorForModel to the method.

Comment: the EditorForModel should automatically create javascript variable names that will be recognized my mvc when you click the action link and resubmit the page to MVC.

Comment: perhaps there is an access or a naming issue with your model object / properties.

Comment: Please post your model object and the controller method where you are trying to receive your model object.

Comment: hmm... I apologize for missing this... but also when you use your editorFor  and other similar statements in your view you specify the model property.
something like..
@Html.EditorForModel(model => Model.PropertyName)

Comment: The compiler doesn't recognize that syntax at all.  Does the model binding need to be different for it to work that way?

Comment: I think Stephen Muecke made a key point..  it may not be posting the information needed to create the model when following an action Link.